# How to load images from firebase storage and loop to each button by objective-c

Tags: objective-c, firebase, ios9, firebase-storage, imageset

I am learning iOS and I am trying to load images from a folder in firebase storage. After that, I need to loop them to buttons which show those images. I am learning objective-c so anyone can help me to give an example, thanks

Comment: Did you check the [Create a Storage Reference on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference) ?

Comment: I checked it but it only make a reference to a folder or to specific of a file. My aim is trying to get all files in that folder and retrieved as an array or a dictionary. Can we do like that?